# Como solucionar error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’ en C++

Tags: c++, archivo, condiciones, dev-c++, else

El programa que estoy haciendo es un contador de palabras. La idea es que el programa lea el archivo txt (el cual contiene 10 frases) y cuente la cantidad de palabras que tiene. Para ello, mi idea es la de contar los espacios en blanco y asi sacar la cantidad de palabras de ese archivo, el tema es que me aparece este error en el 'Else', tampoco se si mis comandos para el contador estan bien del todo, porque cuando compilé la ultima vez (antes de que me saliera este error en el 'else' no frenaba el bucle while y me aparecia en pantalla cadenas de numeros que no paraban). Gracias de antemano para el/la que me pueda ayudar.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 #include<iomanip>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<cstdio> 
 using namespace std;

 int main(){ 

string frases;
ifstream archivo; //Elijo el archivo txt
int cant_palabras = 0; //Defino una variable para contarlas palabras que empiece en 0

archivo.open("frasesDeBjarme.txt"); //Abro el archivo.
cout<<"El archivo se abrio correctamente";

if(archivo.is_open()){ //Verifica que exista el archivo
   getline(archivo, frases);
   
}
   

while(!archivo.eof()){
    archivo>>frases;
    cant_palabras++;
cout<<"La cantidad de palabras es de  "<<cant_palabras<<endl;
getline(archivo, frases);

}

return cant_palabras+1;


{
getline(archivo, frases);
}

{
   archivo.close(); //Cierro el archivo
}

else {
cout <<"No se pudo abrir el archivo  " << endl;

}



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

el error se produce debido a que el `if` que has puesto para comprobar si se abrió el archivo no está justo antes del `else`, si no que has escrito varias líneas de código entre ellos. El código corregido (y haciendo un par de cambios adicionales) quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string frases;
  ifstream archivo; //Elijo el archivo txt
  unsigned int cant_palabras = 0; //Defino una variable para contarlas palabras que empiece en 0

  archivo.open("texto.txt"); //Abro el archivo.
  

  if(archivo.is_open()){ //Verifica que exista el archivo
      cout<<"El archivo se abrio correctamente"<<endl<<endl;
     
      for(cant_palabras=0;!archivo.eof();cant_palabras++){
          archivo>>frases;
          cout<<"La cantidad de palabras es de  "<<cant_palabras<<endl;

      } 
    
      archivo.close();
     
  }else cout<<"El archivo no se puedo abrir"<<endl;
     
  
  return 0;
}
```

En los cambios adicionales que he hecho, han sido:

1. Solo lea el archivo si lo ha abierto, tratar de leer el archivo sin saber si está abierto o no, solo generaría errores. Además cierro el archivo una vez sepa que está abierto y haya realizado todo el proceso, en caso de no haber abierto el archivo si se tratase de cerrarlo podría producir errores también.
2. `getline(,)` es una función que nos da una línea completa del fichero que estamos leyendo, de manera que al introducir esta función dentro del bucle mientras leemos todas las palabras lo único que va a hacer es saltarse líneas completas de manera que al final no vamos a obtener el número de palabras del archivo.
3. Esto no es necesario pero personalmente me gusta hacerlo, la variable con la que vamos a contar el número de palabras del archivo siempre va a tomar valores positivos (un archivo no puede tener un número negativo de palabras). De manera que la variable `cant_palabras` la inicializo como `unsigned int` en vez de `int`.

Comment: Gracias por tus aclaraciones @pablo gac, peroo me aparece este error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('  la verdad es que no reconozco este error, si sirve la aclaracion estoy usando un compilador online de c++ (por las dudas lo aclaro si sirve) te agradezco la calidad de tu explicacion, estoy aprendiendo y fuiste sumamente claro.

Comment: Solucione el problema, era un error de sintaxis pero @pablo gac, me figura el mensaje del 'ELSE' : No se pudo abrir el archivo.